# Guard installed packages from upgrade when installing new packages with pip

Tags: python, pip

Imagine I have two packages `foo` and `bar` where `foo` is a dependency of `bar`. `foo` is already installed and I now want to install `bar` with `pip`. Is it possible to do that without upgrading `foo`? In particular I want to install the latest version of `bar` that is satisfied with the installed version of `foo`.

From `pip help install`

```
--upgrade-strategy <upgrade_strategy>
                            Determines how dependency upgrading should be handled
                            [default: only-if-needed]. "eager" - dependencies are
                            upgraded regardless of whether the currently installed
                            version satisfies the requirements of the upgraded
                            package(s). "only-if-needed" -  are upgraded only when
                            they do not satisfy the requirements of the upgraded
                            package(s).
```

As far as I see this only covers the cases "always update" and "only update if needed", but not "never update" as I need it.

Comment: I've had similar issues. The best I've done as a solution is finding a working combination, and putting the "pip freeze" output in a requirements file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install bar` (no upgrade flags at all) should do what you want. pip should pick the currently-installed `foo` unless `bar` explicitly says that version is not compatible. The new (2020) resolver is also capable of finding a `bar` version that can work with the currently-installed `foo` version, by automatically trying available versions one by one (called *backtracking*), and installing that. The 2020 resolver is an opt-in feature in pip 20.2, available via `--use-feature=2020-resolver`, and is schedule to become the default in 20.3 (planeed release in October 2020).

The caveat, however, is that Python packaging does not provide a way to discover version conflicts without downloading the package (sometimes even building from source).<sup>[1](https://dustingram.com/articles/2018/03/05/why-pypi-doesnt-know-dependencies/)</sup> This would be a problem if the package `bar` is costly to download (e.g. `tensorflow`) and/or build (e.g. you’re installing `numpy` on less-supported platforms like Alpine Linux). In that case, the only choice would be to specify the version manually, since pip has no way to know what version of `bar` can be used, unless you tell it explicitly, without trying to download various versions of it.